# using Tikz to create a maze

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-pic, tikz-graphs

I created this figure with `microsoft powerpoint` but I'd like to make a similar one using latex because I am writing my document in latex.
[image]

I already asked how I can make [similar maze structure](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/564731/using-tikz-to-generate-some-figures) but in the response it is hard to remove some part of periphery to keep the red region without removing the whole circle. It would be even better structure if the extra light blue space between 2,3,4,5,7 steps will be removed and only the corresponding cells and middle region remain. I appreciate if someone suggest how I can modify the previous answer to get this image or with mentioned changes.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I let the author of the previous answer modify his figure because I didn't follow the same way to build this figure.
As I didn't quite understand everything you want, here is a first approach.

- I use nodes, 3 in the form of a circle, 3 in the form of a pentagon. The latter are used to place the text at the top of these pentagons.
- The radii of the circles are set, by modifying these parameters, everything is calculated automatically.
- Not having recognized the font you used, I didn't write the text.
  If you have any questions, I'm listening.

Translated with [www.DeepL.com/Translator](http://www.DeepL.com/Translator) (free version)

## Update

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
%\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,calc}
\begin{document}
\def\ultrad{60mm}
\def\bigrad{45mm}
\def\smallrad{30mm}

\def\pentasmall{20mm}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[name=cercle3,shape=circle,minimum width=\ultrad] {};%invisible circle
\node[name=cercle2,shape=circle,minimum width=\bigrad] {};
\node[name=cercle1,shape=circle,draw=cyan!30!violet,fill=cyan!60!violet!40,minimum width=\smallrad] {};
% 3 pentagon used to place text at their corner
\node[name=penta1, shape=regular polygon,rotate=108,draw=cyan!50!violet,
fill = blue!80!violet!20, inner sep=.5cm,minimum width=\pentasmall]
{};
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\pentamed{(\bigrad+\smallrad)/2}
\node[name=penta2, shape=regular polygon,inner sep=0pt,minimum width=\pentamed,rotate=108]{};
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\pentabig{(\bigrad+\ultrad)/2}
\node[name=penta3, shape=regular polygon,inner sep=0pt,minimum width=\pentabig,rotate=108]{};

\node[align=center] at (penta1){Start\\  1};
\foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \j using \i+24]in {-30,42,...,320}{
    \draw (cercle1.\i)--(cercle2.\i)arc[start angle=\i,end angle=\j,radius=\bigrad/2] (cercle1.\j)--(cercle2.\j);}
%\foreach \i/\j in {-90/2,-18/{R\\3},54/5,126/7,198/4}
%    \node[align=center] at ($(cercle1.\i)!.5!(cercle2.\i)$){\j};

\node[align=center,rotate=108] at (penta2.corner 1){J\\4};
\node[align=center] at (penta2.corner 2){2};
\node[align=center] at (penta2.corner 3){3};
\node at (penta2.corner 4){5};
\node at (penta2.corner 5){7};

% red 
\draw[fill=red](cercle2.42)--(cercle3.42)arc[start angle=42,end angle=66,radius=\ultrad/2]--(cercle2.66)arc[start angle=66,end angle=42,radius=\bigrad/2];
\draw[fill=red](cercle2.114)--(cercle3.114)arc[start angle=114,delta angle=24,radius=\ultrad/2]--(cercle2.138)arc[start angle=138,delta angle=-24,radius=\bigrad/2];

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

## Old answer

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
%\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,calc}
\begin{document}
\def\ultrad{60mm}
\def\bigrad{45mm}
\def\smallrad{30mm}

\def\pentasmall{1cm}
\tikzset{
shape example/.style= {color = black!30,
draw=cyan!50!violet,
fill = blue!80!violet!20,
very thick,
inner xsep = 2.5cm,
inner ysep = 0.5cm,
rotate=108}
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[name=cercle3,shape=circle,minimum width=\ultrad] {};%invisible circle
\node[name=cercle2,shape=circle,draw,fill=cyan!20,minimum width=\bigrad] {};
\node[name=cercle1,shape=circle,draw=cyan!30!violet,fill=cyan!60!violet!40,minimum width=\smallrad] {};
% 3 pentagon used to place text at their corner
\node[name=penta1, shape=regular polygon, shape example, inner sep=.5cm,minimum width=\pentasmall]
{};
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\pentamed{(\bigrad+\smallrad)/2}
\node[name=penta2, shape=regular polygon,inner sep=0pt,minimum width=\pentamed,rotate=108]{};
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\pentabig{(\bigrad+\ultrad)/2}
\node[name=penta3, shape=regular polygon,inner sep=0pt,minimum width=\pentabig,rotate=108]{};

\node[align=center] at (penta1){Start\\  1};
\foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \j using \i+24]in {-30,42,...,320}{
    \draw (cercle1.\i)--(cercle2.\i);
    \draw (cercle1.\j)--(cercle2.\j);}
%\foreach \i/\j in {-90/2,-18/{R\\3},54/5,126/7,198/4}
%    \node[align=center] at ($(cercle1.\i)!.5!(cercle2.\i)$){\j};

\node[align=center,rotate=108] at (penta2.corner 1){J\\4};
\node[align=center] at (penta2.corner 2){2};
\node[align=center] at (penta2.corner 3){3};
\node at (penta2.corner 4){5};
\node at (penta2.corner 5){7};

% red 
\draw[fill=red](cercle2.42)--(cercle3.42)arc[start angle=42,end angle=66,radius=\ultrad/2]--(cercle2.66)arc[start angle=66,end angle=42,radius=\bigrad/2];
\draw[fill=red](cercle2.114)--(cercle3.114)arc[start angle=114,delta angle=24,radius=\ultrad/2]--(cercle2.138)arc[start angle=138,delta angle=-24,radius=\bigrad/2];

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I want that remove the curve line between 2,3,4, 5,7 cells and basically it looks like more a star shape but with two bigger arms. Does it make sense? The same as you did here compared to the previous answer but with inner cells. no line connects outer parts of 2,3,4.

Comment: @Dalek I don't know if I understood correctly, does this now correspond to your expectations?

Comment: yeah it is thanks

Answer (score 3):

Another option. In this case, outer segments are drawn with arcs. If you don't want the border, they could be drawn with just an arc with the correct `line width`.

As a first solution all angles are defined by hand, but it's not too difficult to define them automatically.

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm, tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, intersections, decorations.text}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [circle, minimum size=6cm, draw, draw= blue!20!black,fill=blue!20] (a) {} ;
    \node [draw,minimum size=4cm,inner sep=0pt,regular polygon,regular polygon sides=5,shape border rotate=180, align=center, fill=blue!80] (b) {Start\\ 1};
    \foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \j using 30+\i] in {39,111,183,255,327}{
    \draw[fill=cyan] (\i:3) arc (\i:\j:3)--++(\j:1) arc(\j:\i:4)--cycle;
    \draw[fill=red] (\i:4) arc (\i:\j:4)--++(\j:1) arc(\j:\i:5)--cycle;
    }
    \foreach \i [count=\ni] in {54,126,...,342}{
        \node[rotate=\i-90] at (\i:3.5) {\ni};
        \node[rotate=\i-90] at (\i:4.5) {\ni};
    }           
    
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update:**

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm, tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, intersections, decorations.text}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [circle, minimum size=6cm, draw, draw= blue!20!black,fill=blue!20] (a) {} ;
    \node [draw,minimum size=4cm,inner sep=0pt,regular polygon,regular polygon sides=5,shape border rotate=180, align=center, fill=blue!80] (b) {Start\\ 1};
    
    \foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \j using 30+\i] in {39,111,183,255,327}
        \draw[fill=cyan] (\i:3) arc (\i:\j:3)--++(\j:1) arc(\j:\i:4)--cycle;
    \foreach \i [count=\ni] in {54,126,...,342}
        \node[rotate=\i-90, ] at (\i:3.5) {\ni};        
    
    \foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \j using 30+\i] in {39,111}
        \draw[fill=red] (\i:4) arc (\i:\j:4)--++(\j:1) arc(\j:\i:5)--cycle;
    \foreach \i [count=\ni] in {54,126}
        \node[rotate=\i-90, ] at (\i:4.5) {\ni};
            
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @lgnasi great but is it possible to remove extra cells on top of 3,4,5?

Comment: @Dalek Please, look at updated solution.

Comment: how is it possible to change the labels in the cells because I can't find in the code where we can manipulate them?

Comment: @Dalek I used the `foreach` (`\ni`) to fill the cells, but you can forget it and use independent nodes to put whatever you want inside them.

Comment: @Ignais Thanks for answering my question if you don't mind I have another question: how can i change the color of 3rd cell or just one of the red cells to other color? Thanks :)

Comment: @Dalek everything which is drawn with a `foreach` can be drawn isolated. Therefore, forget `foreach` and draw every piece on its own and you will be able to change colors, text, whatever.